# Op-amp circuit and simulation

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

I solved the following circuit (by which I mean finding the output voltage) and I tried simulating it to check my results. This is the main circuit, without the op-amp power supply connected:

[image: op-amp circuit]

And this is the circuit I am simulating with the op-amp power supply connected:

[image: op-amp circuit with power supply connected]

The 2 amplifiers are the univeral op-amp from LTSpice. I tried other varieties of op-amps from LTSpice and the results didn't change.

My solution to the circuit goes as follows. First I noticed R4 and R5 make up a voltage divider, so the voltage at the non-inverting input of the first op-amp is:
$$\frac{R_5}{R_5+R_4}V_O=\frac12V_O$$

By summing point constraint:
$$V_X=\frac12V_O, V_Y=0$$.

Considering R1 and C1, since their currents are equal:
$$\frac{V_1-V_X}{R_1}=C_1\frac{d}{dt}(V_X-V_Z)$$

Now for R2 and R3:
$$\frac{V_Z-0}{R_2}=\frac{0-V_O}{R_3}$$

Since the 2 resistors are equal:
$$V_Z=-V_O$$

Using this equality and the one obtained from the summing point constraint in the differential equation:
$$\frac{V_1-\frac12V_O}{R_1}=C_1\frac{d}{dt}(\frac12V_O+V_O)$$

$$2-\frac12V_O=\frac32R_1C_1\frac{d}{dt}V_O$$

$$4-V_O=\frac3{10}\frac{d}{dt}V_O$$

To solve this differential equation I differentiated once again:
$$-V'=\frac3{10}V_O''$$

$$\frac{V_O''}{V_O'}=-\frac{10}3$$

$$\ln(V_O')=-\frac{10}3t+C$$

$$V_O'=e^{-\frac{10}3t+C}=e^{-\frac{10}3t}\cdot c$$

Substituting back into the diff equation:
$$4-V_O=ce^{-\frac{10}3t}$$

When $t=0$, $V_O=0$ so $4=ce^0=c$:
$$4-V_O=4e^{-\frac{10}3t}$$
$$V_O=4-4e^{-\frac{10}3t}$$
$$V_O=4(1-e^{-\frac{10}3t})$$

Considering this result, I expected to see the output voltage start at 0 and getting up to 4 pretty quickly, however upon simulating I got the following output which is just a flat line at almost 4V:
[image: voltage plot from LTSpice]

I am quite new to electronics, so I think I made a mistake somewhere in my analysis of the circuit but I can't figure out where. Is the initial value that I used for the output wrong? Should I use a different op-amp in LTSpice, or perhaps change some op-amp settings?

Comment: Different simulators handle initial conditions differently and not always as you would expect. Some have user defined options for the initial conditions. Here, the best option might be to change V1 to a slow square wave.

Comment: Using a square wave actually produces the expected output. Thank you!

Comment: You should use the s notation. It would be faster searching the solution.

Comment: Try changing your simulation command to `.tran 1 uic` or `.tran 1 startup`.

Comment: A series connection of two inverting opamp blocks with overall feedback makes a positive feedback loop (two signal inversions within a loop). This means: Instability resp. saturation.

Comment: Look more closely @LvW. The loop has only one inversion.

Comment: OK - I am becoming old. Of course, the loop has only one inversion. Sorry for my comment.

Comment: Doubling up on Hearth’s comment here. LTspice automatically will solve your circuit for when the voltages are at steady state. If you want to start it at zero, it’s best to use the `startup` flag which is a checkbox for “Start external DC supply voltages at 0V” in the Edit Simulation Command window. Another tip is that `UniversalOpamp1` doesn’t use the supply rails so you don’t need to connect them. `UniversalOpamp2` however does. Also, the square wave trick will only work if the first parameter `Vinitial` is zero.  Because that's what determines the DC operating point.

Comment: 200V op-amp supply?

Comment: @Antonio51 I was solving that circuit in preparation for an exam where I won't have access to laplace tables.

Comment: @Hearth that also works. I gotta figure out what all those options do

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I just set it to something that was higher than the other voltages in my circuit assuming that's enough voltage to make things work well